# Creating contour plots

Tags: r

I want to construct a filled contour plot (in ggplot ideally). I am creating my data frame by:

```
b1 = 35
b2 = 20

d = data.frame(slope1 = rep(seq(1,5,length.out = 50)),
               X1 = rep(seq(0.2,10.2,length.out = 50),each=50))

d$slope2 = with(d, slope1*(1-X1))
d$z1 = with(d, (b1 - b2)/(slope1 - slope2))

p = ggplot(d, aes(x=slope2, y=slope1, z=z1)) +
             stat_contour()
p
```

But I get the error:

> Error in contourLines(x = sort(unique(data$x)), y = sort(unique(data$y)),  : 
>     dimensions of 'x', 'y' and 'z' do not match

I know I am missing something fundamental. How do I construct a filled contour plot from this data frame?

Comment: see perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062492/contour-lines-in-ggplot2