# How to add contour line to tile plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tile

I have a set of data predicted by a model. I'm plotting it with geom_tile().

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=rep(seq(0,10,by=.1),each=101),
                    y=rep(seq(10,20,by=.1),times=101))
df1$z <- ((.1*df1$x^2+df1$y)-10)/20

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,size=5,color=z),data=df1)+
  geom_point(size = 16, shape = 15) 

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, fill="blue",alpha = z)) + geom_tile()
```

How can I add some contour lines to it at specific values (e.g. z=0.9, 0.95, 0.99)? Alternatively, geom_tile can be changed to any suitable continuous / contour / raster plot function.

Comment: Maybe `geom_contour`? Actually `stat_contour`? As shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062492/contour-lines-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, z = z, fill = z))+
  geom_tile()+
  geom_contour()
```

[image]

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.